# give random number on last created class JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to give the last created class a number, I know that in Jquery i could use `:last` but how is it in JavaScript ?
I have tried a loop but it does not really do it ? Any suggestions ?

This is what i have for now.

```
   var x=document.getElementsByClassName("sticker");
    for (var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){

    x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);


    <div class="sticker"></div>
    <div class="sticker"></div>
    <div class="sticker">155477</div>
```

Comment: `x[x.length-1].innerHTML = '...';`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that i fully understood what you mean but i think that you want the following:

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("sticker");
x[x.length-1].innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
```

Comment: That did it. 
So I really didn't need the loop though. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("sticker");
x[x.length - 1].innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the last element in the collection by using the `length` for index computation:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sticker");
if (x.length)
    x[x.length-1].innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for the last iteration of your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
   if (i == x.length - 1) {
      x[i].className = x[i].className + " newclass";
   }
}
```

Comment: why bother with the loop at all?

Comment: @James I assumed the loop was part of his other logic as he didn't close it off.

Comment: oh okay you imagined other stuff going on in the loop, I get it =)

Comment: @James Although it would still be faster to access the array key directly outside the loop instead of testing for it on each iteration which didn't occur to me at the time.